# Copy null terminated char array to std::string respecting buffer length

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, char

Maybe it's just the lack of coffee, but I'm trying to create a `std::string` from a null-terminated `char` array with a known maximum length and I don't know, how to do it.

```
auto s = std::string(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

.. was my favorite candidate but since C++ strings are not null-terminated this command will copy `sizeof(buffer)` bytes regardless of any contained '\0'.

```
auto s = std::string(buffer);
```

.. copies from `buffer` until `\0` is found. This is almost what I want but I can't trust the receive buffer so I'd like to provide a maximum length.

Of course, I can now integrate `strnlen()` like this:

```
auto s = std::string(buffer, strnlen(buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
```

But that seems dirty - it traverses the buffer twice and I have to deal with C-artifacts like `string.h` and `strnlen()` (and it's ugly).

How would I do this in modern C++?

Comment: It's either null-terminating or has length of exactly sizeof(buffer), it cannot be both at the same time.

Comment: That's not true (and I'm surprised about the upvote). A C-buffer provided to any sort of writing function can be pre-allocated with a fixed size. The sequence written to the buffer can still be null-terminated.

Comment: It is not true if you can fit a null-terminated string of length N or more in a buffer of N bytes, for some N. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Anyway this is just a minor nitpick. The correct term would be "possibly null-terminated array of maximal length N" or something similar.

Comment: I get your point. But then it should be called a 'expected to be null-terminanted' :) In my case something's definitively wrong, when the string is not null-terminated but this might happen if the buffer has been too small.

Comment: `A C-buffer provided to any sort of writing function` For this situation I'd pre-allocate an extra char `char buffer[n+1]; buffer[n] = 0;`. Then use `std::string(buffer)` as the string is always null-terminated.

Comment: That's indeed an option - in case you are the owner of the buffer..

Comment: Or just stick null in the last byte of the buffer. Worst case, you lose one character of a string which is already likely to be truncated.

Comment: I was close to suggest to make this an answer but there is one disadvantage in this approach: you need extra effort to identify the error case (string was too large and is not null-terminated any more). This is why I discourage this approach. With `find()` you can still check if the buffer is valid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
const char* end = std::find(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer), '\0');
std::string s(buffer, end);
```

Comment: Doesn't it still traverse the buffer twice?

Comment: @songyuanyao: Depending on how you look at it, yes (one traversal to find the length, then one to copy the bytes).  But this is unavoidable because you simply cannot know the correct size to allocate until you check the length, and you cannot copy the bytes before you allocate.  A true single-pass solution would always allocate `sizeof(buffer)` regardless of how short the actual content is, which may increase memory consumption significantly.

Comment: Or to put it another way, `std::string s(buffer);` traverses the buffer twice already, and the additional size limit turns out not to be useful unless we don't mind over-allocation. In principle you could make a series of allocations of exponentially increasing size (like a `vector`), but by the time you add up all the intermediate copies you've still traversed the data approximately twice.

Comment: @joeeey: Here's a demo of the code compiling cleanly as written with all compiler warnings enabled: https://godbolt.org/z/r56j5x - if you have a problem with some other version feel free to post your code.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hmm okay I did some more experimenting. I was running into problems because my buffer didn't have the `const` keyword. My line solves this (without making buffer `const`) somehow. If you had any insight, I would love to hear it :)

Comment: @joeeey That's because `buffer` and `end` need to be the same type.  Either use `auto end` or remove the `const` like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3TzTaK

Comment: @JohnZwinck Oh wow doh. That makes sense, I don't know how I missed that (nor how what I had worked). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work in a single pass..

```
auto eos = false;
std::string s;
std::copy_if(buffer, buffer + sizeof(buffer), std::back_inserter(s),
  [&eos](auto v) {
    if (!eos) {
      if (v) {
        return true;
      }
      eos = true;
    }
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: Except for the extra passes needed to copy the characters on reallocation?

Comment: @T.C without knowing how big `buffer` is, it's possibly difficult to make a guess as to whether there will be any reallocations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single-pass solution, start with this:

```
template<class CharT>
struct smart_c_string_iterator {
  using self=smart_c_string_iterator;
  std::size_t index = 0;
  bool is_end = true;
  CharT* ptr = nullptr;
  smart_c_string_iterator(CharT* pin):is_end(!pin || !*pin), ptr(pin) {}
  smart_c_string_iterator(std::size_t end):index(end) {}
};
```

now, gussy it up and make it a full on random-access iterator.  Most of the operations are really simple (`++` etc should advance both `ptr` and `index`), *except* `==` and `!=`.

```
friend bool operator==(self lhs, self rhs) {
  if (lhs.is_end&&rhs.is_end) return true;
  if (lhs.index==rhs.index) return true;
  if (lhs.ptr==rhs.ptr) return true;
  if (lhs.is_end && rhs.ptr && !*rhs.ptr) return true;
  if (rhs.is_end && lhs.ptr && !*lhs.ptr) return true;
  return false;
}
friend bool operator!=(self lhs, self rhs) {
  return !(lhs==rhs);
}
```

we also need:

```
template<class CharT>
std::pair<smart_c_string_iterator,smart_c_string_iterator>
smart_range( CharT* ptr, std::size_t max_length ) {
  return {ptr, max_length};
}
```

now we do this:

```
auto r = smart_range(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
auto s = std::string(r.first, r.second);
```

and at each step we check for both buffer length and null termination when doing the copy.

Now, Ranges v3 brings about the concept of a sentinal, which lets you do something like the above with reduced runtime cost.  Or you can hand-craft the equivalent solution.